# Error in Switch case and not executing the program

Tags: c#

The error is "Control cannot fall through from one case label ('case "B":')"
I am trying to do the following:
Upon starting the application a user will be prompted to login. The first action is to authenticate the user by validating an account exists for the entered username. Once the username has been matched to an account let the account object validate the entered pin (see Account class).
o After authentication, display a welcome message to the customer logged in using their name and display a menu offering options to get balance, deposit to account, withdraw from account, modify customer information, display current transactions, and exit.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Account myCustAcc = new Account();
            Transaction myCustTrans = new Transaction();
            string input, choice = "";
            string adminName, userName= "";
            int adminPin, userPin;
            //Login 
            Console.WriteLine("\t\t*****************WELCOME TO BANKING APPLICATION*********************\n");   
            choice = Console.Readline();  
            switch (choice)
            {
                case "A":
                    choice = "Admin";
                    Console.Write("\nAdminName :");
                    adminName = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.Write("AdminName :");
                    Console.Write("AdminPIN :");
                    adminPin = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    //IT IS DEFINE USERNAME AND PASSWORD

                    if (adminName.Equals("admn1") && adminPin.Equals("9999"))
                    {
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Bank");
                    } 
                    break;  
                case "B":
                {
                    choice = "User";
                    Console.Write("\nUserName :");
                    userName = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.Write("UserName :");
                    Console.Write("PIN :");
                    userPin = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    //IT IS DEFINE USERNAME AND PASSWORD

                    if (userName.Equals("SMD") && userPin.Equals("1212"))
                    {
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                        //Welcome Message with Name 
                        Console.WriteLine("\t\t\t Welcome to Banking Application",userName);
                        Console.WriteLine("\n<<<Please Select Following Menus>>>");
                        do
                        {
                 //With Menu option to get balance, deposit/withdraw from account, modify customer information display current balance and exit
                            Console.WriteLine("\t1> GetBalance");
                            Console.WriteLine("\t2> Deposit");
                            Console.WriteLine("\t3> Withdraw");
                            Console.WriteLine("\t4> Modify");
                            Console.WriteLine("\t5> Display");
                            Console.WriteLine("\t6> Exit");
                            input = Console.ReadLine();
                            switch (input)
                            {
                                case "1":
                                    break;

                                case "2":
                                    break;

                                case "3":
                                    break;

                                case "4":
                                    break;

                                case "5":
                                    break;

                                case "6":

                                default: Console.WriteLine("Exit the Application!!!");
                                    break;
                            }
                        } while (input != "6");
                      }
                    break;                       
                }                   
       }
        //Pause Display
        Console.WriteLine("Press Any key to continue...........");
        Console.ReadLine();  
    }
}
```

}

this is my account class

```
class Account
    {
        //Declare Instance Variables
        private string customerFirstName;
        private string customerLastName;
        private string customerAddress;
        private string customerState;
        private int customerZip;
        private double customerBalance;

        //Class Variables 
        private static string customerUserName;
        private static int customerPin;

        //Retrieve Customer First Name
        public string getCustomerFirstName()
        {
            return customerFirstName;
        }
        //Set Customer Name
        public void setCustomerFirstName(String newFirstName)
        {
            customerFirstName = newFirstName;
        }
        //Retrieve Customer Last Name
        public string getCustomerLastName()
        {
            return customerLastName;
        }
        //Set Customer Last Name
        public void setCustomerLastName(String newLastName)
        {
            customerLastName = newLastName;
        }
        //Retrieve Customer Address
        public string getCustomerAddress()
        {
            return customerAddress;
        }
        //Set Customer Address
        public void setCustomerAddress(string newAddress)
        {
            customerAddress = newAddress;
        }
        //Retrieve Customer State
        public string getCustomerState()
        {
            return customerState;
        }

        //Set Customer State
        public void setCustomerZip(string newState)
        {
            customerState = newState;
        }

        //Retrieve Customer Zip
        public int getCustomerZip()
        {
            return customerZip;
        }

        //Set Customer Zip
        public void setCustomerZip(int newZip)
        {
            customerZip = newZip;
        }

    }
```

Comment: what did you expect to happen. If the input != 6 then nothing happens and you exit the loop if the input is 6 then you write to the console and exit the loop

Comment: I want first admin to login and it is correct and the user logins and if the user is correct then it is allowed to choose from the menu options

Comment: If you want the code in case A to run **and** then the code in case B to run, then you shouldn't be using a `switch` at all. Take the `switch` out (and the "case" labels).

Answer (score 2):

You need to move the `break` outside of the `if` statement. Also I recommend you to use brackes for case statements as they will make the intent clear(where statement block starts and ends).

Your code have too many execution path inside the single method, which makes code hard to read and hard to maintain. Refactor your code to methods which does only one thing, so that it will be easy to maintain.

Comment: I did change the code as you suggested but the code is not executed

Comment: there is no error. when i run the code , a black window comes and goes away. I cannot see the output screen

Comment: What was the choice you entered? and which line you get the warning?

Comment: Line 97 -  Console.WriteLine("Press the Enter key to Exit");

Comment: With this (menu.cs) class, I need to create an account class. Should i check this in the account class.

Comment: Account objects will contain data:
o name – first and last name of the customer.
o address – number, direction, and street/ave name.
o state – of residence, must only be two letters and all capital letters.
o zip – of residence, must only be numbers and 5 digits.
o username – must be at least 4 characters of mixed letters & numbers.
o pin – must be a 4 digit number.
o balance – dollar amount in customer’s account (updated per withdrawals/deposits).

Answer (score 0):

Your main switch statement is using the choice variable which you are setting to an empty string and then never assigning. It looks like you meant to include a Console.Read after the initial message but forgot it.

Comment: I did add the console.readline. but there is no change in the execution of the code

Answer (score 0):

The window flickers because 'choice' variable is not initialized to "A" or "B":

```
string input, choice = "";  //<----- here
```

Therefore there is no match for the switch block and the program quits.
Unreachable code warning is issued because you put some lines after the break command.

```
switch (choice)
{
    case "A":
        ...
        break;
    case "B":
        {
            ...
            break; //<--- quits case "B", but the code below belongs to case "B"
        }  

        //Pause Display
        Console.WriteLine("Press the Enter key to Exit");   // <--- here is still considered part of case "B"
        Console.ReadLine();
// case "B" ends here
}   // end of outer switch block.
```

You may want to consider something like this:

```
...
Console.WriteLine("\t\t*****************WELCOME TO BANKING APPLICATION*********************\n");
Console.WriteLine("Choose A or B");
choice = Console.ReadLine();
switch (choice)
{
    case "A":
        ...
        break;
    case "B":
        ...
        break;
}   // end of outer switch block.

//Pause Display
Console.WriteLine("Press the Enter key to Exit");
Console.ReadLine();
```